# BAT to change assigned drive letter, copy contents of drive to C: then run program off C:

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation, directory

Currently running a flash to Map drive letter to the flash drive each time I put into another system. After in which the drive closes and the bat does not finish executing.

The script I wrote works fine but I have to run the batch once to assign the designated letter then run it again to do the rest of the task after the letter has been assigned.

What I am trying to do is copy contents of a flash drive to the C:(folder I created with md)

Then execute a file that I just copied over.

Here is what I have so far. Just want to get this done to automate my update process among multiple clients.

for /f "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%A in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr "PC Setup Tools"') do (
set Acedrive=%%B
(echo select volume %%A
echo assign letter=P) | diskpart
)

mkdir c:\dellutil

xcopy "P:\BIOS and Driver Update Utility\SourceFiles" "c:\dellutil"

regedit.exe /s c:\dellutil\runonceLaunch3.reg

Manage-bde.exe -protectors -disable c:

"C:\dellutil\DellCommandUtility.EXE"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use following code in your batch file on the flash drive?

```
@echo off
rem Make directory of batch file the current directory.
pushd "%~dp0"

rem Copy files from directory "BIOS and Driver Update Utility\SourceFiles"
rem of current drive - the drive of the batch file - to C:\DellUtil whereby
rem XCOPY automatically creates the directory if not already existing.
rem A relative path starting with a backslash is relative to root of
rem current drive.
xcopy "\BIOS and Driver Update Utility\SourceFiles" "C:\DellUtil\" /H /I /Q /R /Y

regedit.exe /s C:\DellUtil\runonceLaunch3.reg
Manage-bde.exe -protectors -disable c:
"C:\DellUtil\DellCommandUtility.exe"

rem Restore previous current directory.
popd
```

This is definitely easier than changing the letter for the flash drive which can always fail if another drive has already letter P.

Also there is the good old command **SUBST**. Run in a command prompt window `subst /?` for details about this command.

Comment: This is fantastic. Worked perfectly. I thank you so much. I feel stupid now haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The SUBST command worked fine for me. My problem is simpler; I occasionally use a different external drive to the one I normally use and it gets allocated a different letter, even if the original external drive is missing. When this happens, none of my links work. Up until now I have been clicking my way through settings to disk management and reassigning the drive letter, but a simple batch file using subst has made life easier:

echo off

echo About to substitute drive letter E for drive letter F

echo If a drive is already connected to E this must be removed first!

echo Press Ctrl-C to abort

pause

subst F: E:\